# Do indicator/p-V diagrams only show reversible processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, reversibility, volume

In Equilibrium Thermodynamics, Adkins, it is stated that

> Since equilibrium state corresponds to definite values of the system parameters, we may represent a quasistatic process by plotting...an indicator diagram.... Non-quasistatic processes should not be represented by a line on a p-V diagram.

Now I'm not sure exactly whether quasistatic is the same as reversible here? If so, it is still not quite obviois to me that any line drawn on a p-V diagram represents a reversible process? Does it have to do with the fact that, for a continuous line, and point in the line has only an infintesimally different volume/pressure values to the points either side? Still, non-reversible processes do exist, and a discontinuous jump in pressure ot volume seems unphysical; to me this suggests that any process, whether reversible ot not, would be represented by a continuous line on any parameter graph, p-V or any other...

Wikipedia's article on P-V graphs did not mention reversibility, so the statement in Adkins is leaving me stumped!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with representing a non-quasistatic process on a $PV$ digram is that during such a process in general pressure is not homogeneous throughout the system, so you cannot assign any definite value to the variable $P$. The same is also true for temperature.